# Password Checker

Tags: javascript, css, html5

In my second post I am looking for the way to change answer dynamically.
As you can see there it changes when I completely fill the input. I want it to change for every letter typed . I will be gratefull guys !

```js
var passwordField = document.forms["takis"]["hero"];
var checkContrainer = document.getElementById("contrainer");

function sila(){
    if(passwordField.value.length >= 8 && passwordField.value.match(/[0-9]+/)!= null && passwordField.value.match(/[a-z]+/)!= null && passwordField.value.match(/[A-Z]+/)!= null)
        checkContrainer.innerHTML = '<h2 style="color:#449055"> Very Strong </h2>';
    else if(passwordField.value.length >= 8 && passwordField.value.match(/[0-9]+/)!= null)
        checkContrainer.innerHTML = '<h2 style="color:#AAEE99"> Strong </h2>';
    else if((passwordField.value.length >= 8 && passwordField.value.match(/[a-z]+/)!= null && passwordField.value.match(/[A-Z]+/)!= null) || passwordField.value.length >= 6 && passwordField.value.length <= 7 && passwordField.value.match(/[0-9]+/)!= null && passwordField.value.match(/[a-z]+/)!= null && passwordField.value.match(/[A-Z]+/)!= null)
        checkContrainer.innerHTML = '<h2 style="color:yellow"> Medium </h2>';
    else
        checkContrainer.innerHTML = '<h2 style="color:red"> Weak </h2>';
}

passwordField.addEventListener("change", sila);
```

```css
body
{
  background-color: #06619A; 
  margin: 0;
}
form
{
  background-color: #30A4C8;
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 80px;
  border: 2px #114577 solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
div
{
  background-color: #444444;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px #333333 solid;
  margin-top: 2px;
  height: 70px;
}
input
{
  outline: 0;
  border: 2px #114577 solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: 80%;
}
input:hover
{
  border-color: #996655;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
input:not(:hover)
{
  transition: 0.5s;
}
h1
{
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial Black";
  color: white;
  background-color: #30A4C8;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px #114577 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="setaki.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Password Checker v26.5 <sup>Really hard work no scam !</sup></h1>
    <form name="takis">
        Hasło: <input type="password" name="hero">
        <div id="contrainer">
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="mmn.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use data to control how password strength is decided.  Make a list of objects with properties that describe each level of strength.

This makes it easy to compare strengths.  In your code, `12345678` is classified as "Strong."  It's not!

Matching `[a-z]+` is the same as matching `[a-z]` if you aren't saving the match.

Use CSS classes to control appearance.

Use dot notation for constant property names:  `object.thing` instead of `object["thing"]`.

```js
const elemInput = document.forms.takis.hero;
elemInput.addEventListener("input", sila);

function sila() {
    const elemStrength = document.getElementById("strength"),
        strength = pwRate( elemInput.value ),
        classes = "strength " + strength.replace( /[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, '' );
        
    elemStrength.className = classes;
    elemStrength.textContent = strength;
}

function pwRate(pw) { 
    const ranks = [ 
        { rank: "Very Strong",
          minLength: 8,
          minParts: 3,
        },
        { rank: "Strong",
          minLength: 8,
          minParts: 2,
          mustMatch: "digit",
        },
        { rank: "Medium",
          minLength: 8,
          minParts: 2,
        },
        { rank: "Medium",
          minLength: 6,
          minParts: 3,
        },
        { rank: "Weak",
          minLength: 3 // let the user type a few before calling him weak
        }
    ];
    
    const parts = { digit: /[0-9]/,
                    upper: /[A-Z]/,
                    lower: /[a-z]/,
                    other: /[^A-Za-z0-9]/
                  };
    
    const hasParts = Object.keys( parts )
            .filter( p => parts[p].test(pw) )
            .reduce( (matches, key) => matches[key]=1 && matches, {} ),
        nParts = Object.keys( hasParts ).length;
    
    for (var rank of ranks) {
        if (
            (!rank.minLength || pw.length >= rank.minLength)
            &&
            (!rank.minParts || nParts >= rank.minParts)
            &&
            (!rank.mustMatch || hasParts[ rank.mustMatch ])
        ) return rank.rank
    }
    return "";
}
```

```css
.strength             { background-color: #444444; }
.strength.VeryStrong  { color: #449055 }
.strength.Strong      { color: #aaee99 }
.strength.Medium      { color: yellow }
.strength.Weak        { color: red }
```

```html
<form name="takis"> Password: <input type="password" name="hero"> </form>
<div id="strength" class="strength" />
```